# Lock screen appears after login

Tags: login, lock-screen

Suddenly, I'm unable to login to Ubuntu. When I login. I get to this lock screen:-

[image]

This is copied from google. What I get is a faded version of this prompt.
The only thing I did was a `visudo` to give root permissions to my user and an `apt-get install lxde`.

I was able to use LXDE and all other environments until I restarted.

Comment: Can you log in from there?

Comment: @the_Seppi I can't type anything there, its kinda' faded and I can't type. Also, when logged in I can lock the screen from Gnome Panel which brings out a brighter version of the prompt where I can type but when I click on Unlock, it gets back to the previous state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following steps,

press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

Run the command `ls -lah`

If you see the following line(or something very similar) in the output continue with the steps below.

```
-rw------- 1 root root 51 May 23 21:37 .Xauthority
```

run the command

```
chown username:username .Xauthority
```

press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> and try to login to your system again.

I had a similar problem and this worked for me. Hope it helps.

For more information, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/223634/399217)

Comment: That didnt work, I was already the owner of `.Xauthority`, however I don't know why but doing a `chown` on `.dbus` solved the issue.

Comment: @SharadGautam Glad to help